# Split Comment at Each TimeStamp

Tags: r, datetime, text, split, comments

**Hey,
I have a comment with various time stamps in a single cell as follows:-**

2019-07-26 20:36:19 - (Work notes)
Informed the caller that the transactions are removed from Concur. Resolved the INC as no action pending.
Send resolution email to caller, copy paste the response and simplify/summarize the information received from the Eng team  YesUpdate the work notes    YesUpdate the state to Awaiting User    Yes

2019-07-26 10:32:05 - oneflow (Work notes)[code] Hi Team.We have removed those gits.

**What i want is to split this cell into rows so that each time stamp is split with its respective text**.

**Please help. Any code in R or Python will help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python option using `regex`:

```
import re

s = """2019-07-26 20:36:19 - (Work notes) Informed the caller that the [...]
line without timestamp!
2019-07-26 10:32:05 - oneflow (Work notes)[code] Hi Team.We have removed those gits."""

# search for the timestamps
timestamps = re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', s)

# if timestamps were found, obtain their indices in the string:
if timestamps:
    idx = [s.index(t) for t in timestamps] + [None] # add None to get the last part...

    # split the string and put the results in tuples:
    text_tuples = []
    l = len(timestamps[0]) # how many characters to expect for the timestamp
    for i, j in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:]): # use zip to iterate over two sequences at once
        text_tuples.append((s[i:i+l], # timestamp
                            s[i+l:j].strip(' - '))) # part before next timestamp

# text_tuples
# [('2019-07-26 20:36:19',
#   '(Work notes) Informed the caller that the [...]\nline without timestamp!\n'),
#  ('2019-07-26 10:32:05',
#   'oneflow (Work notes)[code] Hi Team.We have removed those gits.')]
```

In this example you will get a list of tuples containing the timestamp and the corresponding rest of the line. If a line has no timestamp, it will not go into the output.

---

edit: extension to a `pandas` `DataFrame` after OP's comment:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# create a custom function to split the comments:
def split_comment(s):
    # search for the timestamps
    timestamps = re.findall(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', s)

    # if timestamps were found, obtain their indices in the string:
    if timestamps:
        idx = [s.index(t) for t in timestamps] + [None] # add None to get the last part...
        # split the string and put the results in tuples:
        splitted = []
        l = len(timestamps[0]) # how many characters to expect for the timestamp
        for i, j in zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:]): # use zip to iterate over two sequences at once
            splitted.append([s[i:i+l], # timestamp
                             s[i+l:j].strip(' - ')]) # part before next timestamp
        return splitted
    return ['NaT', s] # no timestamp found, return s

s0 = """2019-07-26 20:36:19 - (Work notes) Informed the caller that the [...]
line without timestamp!
2019-07-26 10:32:05 - oneflow (Work notes)[code] Hi Team.We have removed those gits."""
s1 = "2019-07-26 20:36:23  another comment"

# create example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'s': [s0, s1], 'id': [0, 1]})

# create a dummy column that holds the resulting series we get if we apply the function:
df['tmp'] = df['s'].apply(split_comment)

# explode the df so we have one row for each timestamp / comment pair:
df = df.explode('tmp').reset_index(drop=True)

# create two columns from the dummy column, 'timestamp' and 'comment':
df[['timestamp', 'comment']] = pd.DataFrame(df['tmp'].to_list(), index=df.index)

# drop stuff we dont need anymore:
df = df.drop(['s', 'tmp'], axis=1)

# so now we have:
# df
#    id            timestamp                                            comment
# 0   0  2019-07-26 20:36:19  (Work notes) Informed the caller that the [......
# 1   0  2019-07-26 10:32:05  oneflow (Work notes)[code] Hi Team.We have rem...
# 2   1  2019-07-26 20:36:23                                    another comment
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but just a bit more guidance:- though the input is in one cell, but i want that output should be in next row for each time stamp.Also how could i again format the distorted timestamp in the original input format. And why have we put 3 double quotes at the start and end of string s? A newbie to python from R hence a bit confused.Thanks

Comment: @SahilJain: sorry if this is a bit confusing. the point is to use regex to search for the timestring pattern. I guess you would do something similar in `R`. `datetime is completely optional. if you simply want to split the line into timestring and rest if it contains a timestring, you can do so as well.

Comment: Thanks. Almost done with the issue, only thing is that we are capturing the text which is in the same line, but the requirement is to capture all text before the next time stamp. For eg the output for 1st time stamp shall be  "2019-07-26 20:36:19 - (Work notes) Informed the caller that the [...] line without timestamp!", the next line shall begin with next till another time stamp and so on. Thanks a lot.:)

Comment: @SahilJain: alright, made a slight modification to get your expected output ;-)

Comment: thanks, i did notice it today. Also if i want to apply it to complete column of dataframe. What changes do i need to make? :)

Comment: so you would like to have `text_tuples` in a dataframe? should the timestamps be the index?

Comment: so i have column with around 1000 comments. The above string is one of the row of that column. Similar operation is to applied on each row. Their unique identity is in  other column as ID which goes from 1 to nth row. :)

Comment: @SahilJain: see my edit. There are a couple of options to do this; this might not be the most pretty solution - but let me know if that is what you need ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i think it will work definitely for all cases except for the one which have 'NIL' comments i.e. neither timestamp nor comment, completely blank. I think we have to check that condition too. Right? :)

Comment: @SahilJain, right, if you have fields with "no value", i.e. None, NaN etc., `regex` / `re.findall()` won't like that. You could either make `split_comment` check if `s` is None or drop such rows from the df before applying the function.